# How to optimize SEO for reddit-like sites with many of ouf outgoing links and "copy pastes"

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, links, user-generated-content

Reddit is quite popular and generates a lot of traffic. However, they must have invented some interesting strategies how to deal with SEO issues.

I mean they have two SEO antipatterns as features.

- Tonns of outgoing links
- A lot of Copy & Paste stuff

How do they perform well? Is it only their gravity (and SEO is just as is). Does the amount of unique content (Like comments generated by users) outweigh the rest?
Or any other relevant strategies they or similar sites use?

Answer (score 1):

The below points apply to Reddit or any site that relies on user-generated content.

1. The content should be **adequately moderated**. Structured moderation
   (involving management staff, community moderators, members, and even
   readers) eliminate or at least limit spam, plagiarised and thin
   content.
2. The site should be selective and careful in trusting **outgoing links**.
   Naturally, most of the outgoing links will be `no-follow`.
3. The site should take care of on-page SEO basics like a good link
   architecture, use of proper canonical URLs, good user experience,
   mobile optimization and so on.

Reddit is no exception and it has to continuously adhere to SEO good practices (summarized in the above 3 points). As a side note, I think (I could be wrong) Reddit will be receiving most of the traffic from direct and repeat visitors.

Comment: Stack exchange removes nofollow on some links (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable ) but in my opinion still uses too much nofollow.   Nofollow could be removed any time there is positive reputation for the person that created the link, the post containing the link, and the site being linked to.  I wouldn't say that "most" outgoing links would have nofollow, but that all outgoing links should have nofollow until they are vouched for by the community.  That vouching could be a decently low bar.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. All 3 points I see as well. Also it my first guess " Reddit will be receiving most of the traffic from direct and repeat visitors". And this would explain it all. It could even work with bad SEO then.